# Align vertex with edge or rather the imagine line between two vertices

Tags: modeling, edges

Next question from a total beginner..

Here is two images of the same thing seen from two angles.

[image: Image from front]
[image: Image from top]

How to i align the two sharp edges to the imaginary point between the two vertices (marked with a face/edge in white)

Is the only option to grab them manually and drag them in place, or is there a smarter way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is not fully specified by the imaginary line.. the sharp edges could be flattened to any plane that contains it.. (they could be twisted at any angle *around* the line)

If there is a *plane* you want to flatten to:

- In the Pivot Center menu in the header, select 'Active Element'
- Select three vertices which define the plane (possibly including the ones at the ends of your imaginary line)
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> to create a Custom Orientation from them, checking 'Use after Creation'
- Select the edges you want to flatten, and then, in vertex mode, one of the vertices that defined the plane
- Hit  <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> to scale the edges onto the plane.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "set pivot to active"?  i dont know how to do that, in fact i dont know what that means ;)

I dont have a plane, but guessing i can construct it based on the imaginary line, or two

Comment: @Stig  The Pivot Center selector  is 2  to the right of the Edit/Object... Mode selector. Or you can hit keyboard '.'(period).

Comment: thanks - didnt know that menu - the period '.' on the numeric is zoom, '.' on normal part of keyboard does nothing as far as i can tell.

Comment: Next question - how do i finish this "Create custom Orientation"? all i have is this dialog panel with options...

Comment: The custom orientation is already defined by the verts/edges/faces you have selected when you invoke it. The tool region/F6 panel give you options to name it, use it after creation, (by hitting the constraint key _twice_, the ZZ in the answer) or arrange for it to overwrite previous ones so as not to accumulate a huge list of them. Sorry about the '.' .. I have pie menus enabled, some of the shortcuts are different.